# HTML width rendered ramdomly on IE

Tags: html, width, rendering

I have been debugging the following html code and it has a weird behavior.
Everytime, when I load the page in IE, the browser seems doesn't pickup the width attribute initially. However, it is working fine after a refresh. This page works on all browser but IE. Could you please give me some tips what's going on here?

Thank you very much

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <title>Money_market</title>
    </head>
    <body lang="3DEN-US" style="3D'tab-interval:.5in'">
        <div id="IDMS_container">
            <div style="text-align:right;" id="logout">User: <b></b> <a href="/www/logout.html?s_pageid=logout">Logout</a></div>
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
                    <li><a href="/www/rate_information.html?s_pageid=rate">Cusip Entry Lookup</a></li>
            <li><a href="/www/new_lookup.html?s_pageid=corpgov">Corp/Gov.<br>Bond Lookup</a></li>
            <li><a href="/www/new_lookup.html?s_pageid=muni">Muni Bond<br>Lookup</a></li>
            <li class="selected"><a href="/www/money_market.html?s_pageid=money">Money Market<br>Lookup</a></li>
            <li><a href="/www/help.html?s_pageid=help">Help</a></li>
                <div class="clear"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div id="symbol">
    <h1>Money Market Lookup:</h1>
    <table>
        <tbody><tr>
        <form method="GET"></form>
            <td class="valign">Issuer:</td>
            <td class="valign"><input type="text" value="" id="form" size="9" name="desc"></td>
            <td class="valign">Coupon:</td>
            <td style="width:100px;" class="valign"><input type="text" value="" id="form" size="4" name="coupon"></td>

            <input type="hidden" value="money" name="s_pageid">
            <td class="valign"><input type="submit" value="Lookup" id="button" name="button"></td>

        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <!--span class="date_form">(Enter Date: MM/DD/YYYY)</span-->
</div>
<div id="quote">

    <table>
        <tbody><tr>
            <th>Issue Name</th>
            <th>Coupon</th>
            <th>Maturity Date</th>
            <th>Bid Evaluation</th>
            <th>Bid Evaluation Date</th>
        </tr>
            </tbody></table>
</div>

            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://www.federated.test.idmanagedsolutions.com/css/IDMS_styles.css">        </div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your HTML. Now different browsers respond differently to errors, so it's no surprise that you get different results. Is it still as bad when you correct all the errors? (That is, when it passes the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org).) Also, is this your whole source? If so, it doesn't have a DOCTYPE, so it will be rendered in quirks mode. And different browsers have different quirks, again causing differences in output.